# Duda con consulta de PostgreSQL 9.1.9 (Group by)

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Me encuentro con una duda a la cual no quiero recurrir a una "mala praxis" si ese fuera el caso. Tengo una consulta en PostgreSQL 9.1.9 que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT VO.AOI, (select count(*) from observaciones.observa OB where OB.AOI like VO.AOI ) cant  
FROM observaciones.vista_completa_observaciones VO  
WHERE VO.numero >100 group by VO.AOI,cant ORDER BY AOI ASC
```

y me muestra una tabla resultado de la siguiente manera (existen mas registros, cerca de 500 aprox.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea principal de esta consulta es que me agrupe las cantidades de aoi como "A001" y que me de el total sumado como la fila 1 y 2, o sea, que AOI "A001" sea igual a 4 y que el aoi "A008" me de igual a 6 (por el resultado de la fila 2, 8 y 9).

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema principal es como transformar una cadena con datos separados por comas en múltiples filas. En postgresql dispones de dos funciones útiles para esto_ `unnest()` que "expande" un array en múltiples filas y `string_to_array()` que transforma una cadena con delimitadores en un array:

```
SELECT s.AOI
       FROM   observaciones.vista_completa_observaciones VO, 
       unnest(string_to_array(VO.AOI, ',')) s(AOI)
```

Esto debiera generarte una fila para cada código `AOI` que tengas ya sea uno o múltiples, separados por coma. Lo que resta es complementar esto con la subconsulta, que te recomiendo quitarla como columna e integrarla mediante un `JOIN`:

```
SELECT S.AOI,
       SUM(T.Cant)
   FROM (SELECT VO.AOI, 
                COUNT(O.AOI) AS Cant
                FROM   vista_completa_observaciones VO
                       LEFT JOIN observa O
                       ON VO.AOI = O.AOI
                GROUP BY VO.AOI
   ) T,
   unnest(string_to_array(T.AOI, ',')) s(AOI)
   GROUP BY S.AOI
```

[Fiddle de prueba](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/556a3/10/0)

Comment: Estimado, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no logro comprender bien la logica de la consulta pero en este caso al probarla me da errores de sintaxis en  cross join "table" y en "select level", voy a seguir probando y te comento. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: ¿Que versión de oracle estás usando?

Comment: Estimado, cometí un gravisimo error, no es PLSQL en lo que estoy haciendo la consulta, es PostgreSQL 9.1.9, editaré la pregunta ahora mismo.

Comment: En postgresql es incluso más sencillo, verifica mi última edición

Comment: De hecho si, las funcionalidades lo hacen mas fácil, pero me dio un error en `VO.AOI` que dice:  _Una función en FROM no puede referirse a otras relaciones en el mismo nivel de la consulta_

Comment: Raro, de casualidad versión 9.3 o inferior?

Comment: Exactamente, es la versión 9.1 pero ya resolví la pregunta, lo añadiré como parte de tu respuesta dado que sin tu orientación, nunca hubiese llegado, muchas gracias!

Comment: Estupendo, de todas formas revisa mi última edición por si te resuelve mejor el tema. Saludos.